# How to impliment __iter__ on an objects dict property keys

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Not sure if the title is clear, but I have an object which has a property that is a dictionary of another type of object. The keys are id's which refer to the object. I'd like to impliment the **iter** method so that it will yield these keys, but I'm not sure how to do so. It should be fairly simple, but I can't find much in the python docs and can't think of an easy way to explain what I'm trying to do in order to search for much.

To further clarify I have an object like this:

```
Object:
  dict = {num: object, num: object, num: object, ...}
```

I want to basically be able to iterate over the keys in the dict by calling the mainobject's **iter** method.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need a method, just `self.__iter__=self.dct.__iter__`. And don't call your vars `dict`!

Answer (score 2):

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.that_dictionary_you_mention)
```

Comment: Sweet, that looks like it'll work. I knew it had to be simple. Though I guess I'd probably have to do self.thatdictionary.keys() since I just want the keys? I'll figure it out in a second now that I have somewhere to go.

Comment: @kryptobs2000: `iter(dictionary)` does iterate over the keys. But if that's unfamiliar to you and your colleagues then adding `.keys()` would make it more obvious (or `iterkeys()` in Python 2).

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.internal_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.internal_dict)
```

Comment: Not to put you off answering, but this answer has already suggested.